# Mathematica script file in Linux - how to export PDF file and close kernel?

Tags: export, linux, scripting

`tmp.m` file:

```
tmp = Table[RandomReal[], {3}, {4}]
Export["test.xlsx", tmp]
Quit[]
```

Then

```
echo "./math -script tmp.m" | at now
```

Works fine, but it does not close the kernel. The process will be still running.

*BUT* if I edit `tmp.m` to

```
tmp = Table[RandomReal[], {3}, {4}]
Export["test.PDF", TableForm@tmp]
Export["test.xlsx", tmp]
Quit[]
```

Then

```
echo "./math -script tmp.m" | at now
```

Will not run. It does not even save the `xlsx` file.

So two questions:

How to export PDF file?
How to make `Quit[]` in a script file?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is really nothing to do with *Mathematica*. Rather it is about your working environment, and as such, it's very unlikely that we can answer it without simply guessing. About the current directory, it is `/proc/<PID>/cwd`; to close them `kill -TERM <PID>`. You will need to become familiar with how your computer is set up and how to work with it, not only for your own sake but because otherwise you risk annoying the administrators and other users with your failed jobs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically not about *Mathematica* itself, but rather the use of it in some unknown environment. The question is therefore unanswerable in this forum.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I know how to kill process in linux and how to check the folder. I want to know how Mathematica works in Linux. I have also rephrased my question, hope it is now more Mathematica focused.

Comment: both work just fine for me with v10. (`Quit[]` is not needed ) running directly (i don't have `at` ). Its either a version issue or something peculiar about `at`.

Answer (score 1):

Chen, use the following in the terminal and both codes should work just fine:

```
math -nohup -run "<<tmp.m" > output
```

any error messages will be in the file "output".  When I run this, I get both the excel sheet and the PDF.  Now, if you try to export graphics without a frontend you can sometimes run into trouble, but you'll find any error messages in the file.

Edit:  I learned about using Mathematica from the command line by reading [Jens Noeckel's page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html).